# Typescript project - how to incorporate imported modules into final build?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have created Typescript project in Visual Studio Code. Added some basic configuration and have used npm to download some libs.

I have simple main.ts file with code of below:

```
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'

  var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), {...});
  chart.render();
```

And tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,        
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
    }
}
```

Project compiles fine but output contains require() calls. Is there any way to configure project build to incorporate imported libs into javascript output?

I'm opened to any suggestions.

Comment: change your `"module": "commonjs"` to something different such as `"module": "es2016"`

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, you might have to actually have to use [`require.js`](https://requirejs.org/) instead of changing the module

Comment: Another way is to use [`es6 modules`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

Comment: Changing to es2015 broke the build. I don't want to use require.js. I would prefer to compile whole into single file.

Comment: I and need browser compatibility on IE11.

Comment: Than it looks like you need to use a secondary compiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: [How to set it up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#babel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use typescript and output a module for usage in the browser you need another compiler that knows how to do this. By following the instructions on the TypeScript website we can use [Browserify](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/integrating-with-build-tools.html#browserify) to transpile into browser code.

First we install local versions of `tsify` and `typescript` (A global version doesn't work):

```
npm install tsify typescript --save-dev
```

Next we write our code:

```
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts'

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), {});
chart.render();
```

Then finally we add the command to our scripts in the **package.json**:

**Note:** `tsify` will automatically read the `tsconfig.json` file. However, [some options are ignored](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify#does-this-work-with)

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify src/index.ts -p [ tsify ] > bundle.js"
  }
}
```

Lastly we build the file:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Thanks very much, bundle.js contains apex inside. I have to investigate other bundler and compilers to have optimal choice for further development. Why did you choose browserify?

Comment: I chose it because it is really easy to setup. There is less configure than say webpack.